# Google Map API V2 Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on a project and I need to include Google Map. I'm using the API v2 and I have some problems to display the map.

```
    package com.lan.me;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Geoloc extends Fragment {

    GoogleMap map;
    View view;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        Geoloc mFrgment = new Geoloc();
        return mFrgment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my Geoloc.java, and in my map.xml i have this :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

I don't have any problem to compile or to launch my app, but when i click on my button, my app dosn't want to work. When i double click on the LogCat, the error seems to be there :

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

But I don't really understand why. Someone have a idea ?

EDIT :

```
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): Process: com.lan.me, PID: 1169
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.lan.me.Geoloc.onCreateView(Geoloc.java:24)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4805)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.lan.me.Geoloc.onCreateView(Geoloc.java:24)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #1: Duplicate id 0x7f090027, tag null, or parent id 0x7f090004 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4791)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
07-29 06:00:14.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     ... 26 more
```

EDIT EDIT :

http://uprapide.com/image/811589-properties_2

Here is the problem ...

Comment: Post your logcat here, no need of image here buddy, just copy and paste, that's it.

Comment: @pratik : I just add my logcat, you can see it on my first post !

Comment: @MD : I just add my logcat, you can see it on my first post !

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to :

1) Extend your Class With Fragment

2) In your fragment xml Take Relative layout and put your fragment in it with id map

3) in Fragment class Add your Fragment xml

4) get map id in onActivityCreated() using below code

```
googleMap=((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

5)there are no fifth step..:)
Thats it

Comment: I already seen this post, but my problem is my class, i'm extended by a Fragment and this is the problem ...

Comment: Hum okay, I will try now and I will tell you if it's work, thanks

Comment: It's better now, I have my :

public class Geoloc extends FragmentActivity {
 
 GoogleMap map;
 View view;
 
    public static FragmentActivity newInstance() {
     Geoloc mFrgment = new Geoloc();
        return mFrgment;
    }

But the problem is the FragemntActivity, it's not possible to cast it into a Fragment (or all the informations i found said no =/)

Comment: yes you cant cast into Fragment So i give you one Suggestion i update my above ans see that..

Comment: yes i see that, now i can compile, but still have some errors on   MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()); (The error page is definitively less full of errors than before ^^)

Comment: I think i found the problem : 
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
I got some errors in the logcat and i think it's because of this. I don't really understand cause i have the export and all i need but still the error

Comment: i think change word class and put there name i mean android:name instead of android class and if your api level below 11 then com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment instead of com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.

Comment: Hi @Jay , it doesn't change anything =/ I just update my logcat and my code on my first post, can you check ?